# Boundary In HttpPost

Tags: java, http-post, boundary

I am working on some HttpPost Request to be sent to a server. But I am stuck with the "boundary" of which I have no idea. This is what the example in the documentation says :

```
Request:
POST /render?method=addJob&version=1000&target=stream HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=boundary
--boundary
Content-Length: ...
Chapter 2 Description of the HTTP interface
18 OpenText Rendition Server RS100000-PGD-EN
X-sourceType: options
X-optionsAs: properties
pageSize=A4
serverSideProfile=Confidential
--boundary
Content-Length: ...
X-sourceType: stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; filename="sourceFile1.xls"
fadjföajdfhaor ofua rela üjadfhkhdaf adfaj f (binary content)
--boundary
Content-Length: ...
X-sourceType: stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; filename="sourceFile2.doc"
X-urlForm: http://server/path/file.jpg
X-formParams: overlayLayer=Background&overlayAlignment=TopLeft
fadjföajdfhaor ofua rela üjadfhkhdaf adfaj f (binary content)
--boundary
Content-Length: ...
X-sourceType: url
X-url:
http://server:8080/archive?get&contRep=WM_101&docId=ICS_1&pVersion=0045
X-contentType: image/tiff
--boundary--
```

I am able to figure out that the part

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=boundary
```

is the header. But I have no idea about the boundary thing mentioned in it. Can you please give a working example to explain this? What it actually is? And you to send this to the server?

This is what I am doing till now.

```java
package method;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.text.html.parser.Entity;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import paramStorage.Data;

public class AddJob {

    private HttpClient client = null;
    private String URL = null;
    private HttpPost post = null;
    private HttpResponse response = null;
    private final String boundary = "--boundary\r\n" + 
                                    "X-sourceType: stream\r\n"+
                                    "pageSize=A4"+
                                    "serverSideProfile=Confidential"+
                                    "--boundary--\r\n";

    public void getSessionId() {
        client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        URL = "http://" + Data.server + ":" + Data.port + "/render?method=addJob&version=1000&target=" + Data.target
                + "&targetContentType=" + Data.targetContentType;
        System.out.println(URL);
        post = new HttpPost(URL);
        post.addHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data; boundary=boundary");
        String body = "--boundary\r\n"+
                "X-sourceType: stream\r\n"+
                "emailFrom: test@domain.com\r\n"+
                "emailTo: test2@domain.com\r\n"+
                "emailSubject: Java Mail\r\n"+
                "--boundary--\r\n";

        try {
            HttpEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(body.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            post.setEntity(entity);
            Header[] headerst = post.getAllHeaders();
            for (Header header : headerst) {
                System.out.println(header);
            }

            response = client.execute(post);
            if (response != null) {

                System.out.println("Status :: " + response.getStatusLine());
                Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
                for (Header header : headers) {
                    System.out.println(header);
                }
                Data.jsessionid = headers[2].getValue();
                System.out.println(Data.jsessionid);

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Hope this will give you an idea about what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boundary is to divide the parts of the message.   I've used it to return some XML in addition to an image or other binary data.   I was doing vision analytics and would return a track record (in xml or json) in addition to an image of the vehicle.   I've also used it to transmit camera calibration.   Various parts of the calibration structure were sent in one region as xml/json/etc and in the other region was a binary table mapping each pixel to its real world location (lat, long, altitude.

Without a boundary, its assumed that the whole response is homogeneous(or user parsed).   You've provided an example.   Depending on the server/clients you have setup, it could be set to the server with a POST or returned from the server with a GET.